# Unable to place COD for guest users

Tags: magento-2.1.7, cash-on-delivery

Unable to place COD for guest user getting below error in console. Once reload the page the error goes away and everything works fine
[image]

No third party module or custom template. Simply giving error.
Plugin to check if COD is available for the post code.

```
public function afterIsAvailable(\Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod $subject, $result)
{
    $postcode = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();
    if (condition) {
                return $result;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Any custom module on checkout?

Comment: No. I added one step in checkout but removed. still getting this error. One plugin I have created to check if COD is available or not afterIsAvaiable method. Please see the updated query

Comment: The default magento isAvailable method has one argument $quote, which i think you need to pass in after method as well as third parameter.

public function isAvailable(\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null)

Comment: @yash7690 for after plugin its not mandatory if you are not using the parameter. Thanks tried this also but no luck

Answer (score 1):

Open following file

vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cashondelivery-method.js

Put this file on your custom theme. (For testing purpose you can direct change file from vendor)

Change following code

```
getInstructions: function() {
     return window.checkoutConfig.payment.instructions[this.item.method];
}
```

with following

```
getInstructions: function() {
     if (typeof window.checkoutConfig.payment.instructions != 'undefined')
          {
              return window.checkoutConfig.payment.instructions[this.item.method];
          }
     }
```

Run following command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Its work but why, don't know. Can you explain :)

Comment: In magento 2.1 there is issue with that. Some how payment instruction object not initiate and return undefined because of that. I have checked object type, before it used.